# Save HTTP response as string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, http, httpresponse

How do I save the body of an HTTP request as string and print it? I'm having an HTML file and I'm sending an HTTP request like this:

```
function loadXMLDoc(str) {
  var url = "http://192.168.178.37?" + str;
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState === 4) {
      window.alert(http.response);
    }
  }

  http.open('GET', url, true);
  http.send();
}
```

On the other side the response looks like this:

```
  char rspText[]  = "value=sensorvalue";
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  client.printlnf("Content-Length: %d", strlen(rspText));
  client.println();
  client.print(rspText);
```

My problem is that the `http.response` which should include to body is always empty. I know that I have probably used the wrong Content-Type. I simply want to send a sensor value back in the response and save it as string for later use.

Comment: It would be very odd for a server to respond with a Content-Type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Typical response types are `application/json` or `text/html` or `text/plain`. Not knowing what your use case is, if you just want a plain string, use `text/plain`.

Comment: Yes I just want a plain string but text/plain somehow doesn't work for me so I tried application/x-www-form-urlencode where I can at least set a value to a key. I really just want to have a plain text with sensor value and access it from the html file. I'm struggling with this for a while now.

Comment: You may be getting an error; check `http.status` and make sure it's 200.

Comment: I can trace the GET request and the response with Wireshark and everything seems fine (text/plain works now). I find my string like this: Line-based text data: text/plain (1 lines). I just want to read that string and save it. Maybe http.response is the wrong way to do this?
Window.alert(http.response) also opens a window but it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You tell the browser to expect `strlen(rspText)` (17) bytes of body, but then by mistake you send the literal string `rspText` (notice the double quotes) rather than the actual response you had prepared.

Problems like these lead to an HTTP protocol error, and it's probably the case that the browser leaves the `.response` property empty when this happens.

---

Also possibly problematic is that HTTP is specified to use CRLF line endings, and it's not clear that your sample server code follows that. Even if browsers are lenient enough to handle LF line endings, there might be some fussy middleware in between that's unsatisfied.

Comment: Oh yes I fixed this mistake but that didn't solve my problem. Maybe you are right with the line endings I will check that. Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to Disable Local File Restrictions in Safari ...

Comment: If your html file is static, and you're loading it like `file:///home/you/your/path/index.js`, then I recommend you run a small static server instead. Big list of easy options, some already built-in and available for you to use: https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255